# How to set maximum length for UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

In `Objective-C`, I am attempting to set a limit of character length for a `UILabel`, but I could not find a way anywhere. For example, a line of text is entered into the `UILabel`, say 100, but if the maximum character length is set to 50, I just want it to cut off at 50 exactly and not even truncate. I just would like for it to cut off once it hits the limit.

I have tried this; but it didn't work:

```
 NSString *string = my_uilabelText; 
 if ([string length] >74) { 
    string = [string substringToIndex:74]; 
 }
```

Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You said you are attempting. What have you tried exactly?

Comment: @soulshined NSString *string = my_uilabelText;
if ([string length] >74) {
    string = [string substringToIndex:74];
} doesn't work.

Comment: Didn't you just say you wanted to cut it off at 50 characters? Why did u do 74? Otherwise that would work fine.

Comment: Please add any relevant posts that can benefit all users to your question itself. Placing them in comments make it hard to read @Walter and people aren't likely to see them

Comment: @DBoyer please take note that I mentioned 'For example' ... Specifically I want it to be set to 74

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, what you actually implemented would work. You just have to ensure your syntax is correct.

Assuming your getting a string from a database:

```
NSString *string = stringFromDatabase;
//execute your conditional if statement
if (string.length > 50) { //meaning 51+
    /* trim the string. Its important to note that substringToIndex returns a
    new string containing the characters of the receiver up to, but not 
    including, the one at a given index. In other words, it goes up to 50, 
    but not 50, so that means we have to do desired number + 1. 
    Additionally, this method includes counting white-spaces */

    string = [string substringToIndex:51];
}
```

Then we must set the labels text, this doesn't happen autonomously. So completely:

```
NSString *string = stringFromDatabase;
if (string.length > 50) { 
    string = [string substringToIndex:51];
}
self.someUILabel.text = string;
```

I think the way you are doing it is probably not user friendly. You're getting the string of a `UILabel` that already has text set and then resetting it. *Instead*, you should set the desired text to the `UILabel` **before** it is called by the delegate

Comment: It is getting the string from a database, so if the string were to exceed the character limit for the UILabel, I would want it to be cut off to meet the maximum length and be displayed for UILabel. Therefore, in that sense, would resetting be a proper method? Or if there's another way, please let me know as I am looking to learn. Thank you

Comment: Yes no problem @Walter ! I like to help people willing to learn! In the example you provided, it would still apply. As soon as you get the string from a database, edit it with the example in my answer, then set it to your `UILabel` so it reduces redundancy. No need to set it to a `UILabel` , just to re-set it, when you already have it from the database to set to that label in the first place. Making sense?

Comment: By the way, just attempted the code and still does not work. The UILabel is placed inside a Table View Cell, so the code would be placed inside the method awakeFromNib, correct? Also someUILabel would be the same text as the my_uilabelText? In other words, self.my_uilabelText.text = string;

Comment: @Walter is your label actually called my_uilabelText ? Do you mind posting your code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` so it's easier for me to understand where your coming from

Comment: the UILabel is named profileDescription. So in the header for the Table View Cell it is set as: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *profileDescription; Now in the .m, the code you suggested would go under the -(void) awakeFromNib{ NSString *string = profileDescription.text;
if (string.length > 50) { 
    string = [string substringToIndex:51];
}
self.profileDescription.text = string; }

Comment: You could put it in `viewDidLoad` or `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it all depends on how your retrieving it from the database. Can you please update your question with those two code blocks (how you retrieve it from your database and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) if it's only one cell that has it then it's not a problem, but if your retrieving multiple strings for multiple cells then it's not a problem either but you would put it in cellForRowAtIndexPath @Walter

Comment: THANK YOU! Just solved it. It belongs in the cellForRowAtIndexPath. You the best! Just accepted your answer :D